# Laravel 5 : php artisan route:list Illuminate\Container\BindingResolutionException]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

When I use the command "php artisan route:list" I have this error

```
[Illuminate\Container\BindingResolutionException]
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $methods ]] in class Illuminate\Routing\Route
```

The command works nicely when I have

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
```

but as soon as i add other routes, I have this exception

**I found the problem :**

I'm doing IOC in the controller and I inject Illuminate\Routing\Route. As soon as i delete the injection its works.

I have BaseController which extends Controller.

The BaseController is

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

/**
 * @var array Options used by the pages
 */
protected $options;

/**
 * @param Route $route
 */
public function __construct(Route $route)
{
    $this->options = Option::getAutoloaded();

    // Load the options for the named route page
    $this->options = array_merge($this->options, Option::getByPage($route->getAction()['as']));

    $this->initListPlugins();
}
```

A controller is

```
class MediasController extends BaseController {


public function __construct(Route $route)
{
    parent::__construct($route);

    $this->options = array_merge($this->options, Option::getByPage('media'));
}
```

Now thre problem is how I fix it :)

Thanx for your help

Comment: Please post the route definitions you're adding for the error to appear.

Comment: For example :Route::get('medias',   ['uses' => 'MediasController@getMediaList', 'as' => 'medias.index']); or even the default auth routes `Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);`

Answer (score -1):

When ever I see this error I think of typo's, so make sure you recheck everything for those.

Just make sure your Route is linked to the correct Controller@function:

```
Route::get('medias', ['uses' => 'MediasController@getMediaList', 'as' => 'medias.index'])
```

Would go to the MediasController in Http/Controllers:

class MediasController extends Controller {

```
public function getMediaList()
{
    return view('medialist');
}
```

}

Also make sure your controller has a correct return to the view.
And if you're using the

```
{!! link_to_route('medias.index', 'Media list') !!}
```

make sure you have the "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev" installed through your composer.json aswell.

Comment: Just to make sure, could you post your controller/route (in full) on your main post. This way it's easier to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: It's the not the problem. As I told the site works perfectly and I only have this trouve when I try to list the routes in the terminal and only in the terminal